# Loading route is very slow

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a very basic Router defined as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('folders', {path: "/"}, function() {
        this.resource('folder', {path: "/folder/:folder_id"});
    });
});
```

And a simple FoldersRoute with a number of logging hooks for trouble-shooting:

```
App.FoldersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('folder');
    },
    actions: {
        loading: function() {
            console.log("FoldersRoute: action(loading)");
        },
        didTransition: function() {
            console.log("FoldersRoute: action(didTransition)");
        },
        willTransition: function() {
            console.log("FoldersRoute: action(willTransition)");
        },
        error: function(error, transition) {
            console.log("FoldersRoute: action(error)");
        }
    }
});
```

Also I am using `DS.RESTAdapter` to hook up to a remote server.

My problem is that the page load is taking up to 10+ seconds and I see that the FoldersRoute is blocking:

`FoldersRoute: action(loading)`

If I log the server side, I see that no requests are being received while blocking and only after will/didTransision is passed.

Idem ditto for network using google devtools.

If I run `curl "http:/.../folders` the request/response is sent/received back immediately.

The really weird thing is that sometimes when I fire up the browser the first time, it works great, and only after refreshing afterwards that it slows down.

Is there some known issue with REST on the chrome browser or something else I am doing wrong?

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.10
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

Comment: This will be hard to debug without seeing it in action.  If you run the perf tools in chrome you can track down expensive code paths.  The most likely candidate is the ajax response or you are putting a ton of bound data on the page.  Can you maybe include the template with an example json response and the model definition?

Comment: And generally the loading hook is only called when the model response is taking a long time to resolve (ajax response)

Comment: When I look in the promises window, I see `DS: RestAdapter#ajax GET to http://.../folders` remains pending for 9 seconds before it is fulfilled. Any ideas on how to debug this would be welcome.

Comment: If you send a `GET` to the same endpoint with something like [DHC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-http-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) (or similar), does it also take that long? 'Cause if it does, your problem could the backend API that is taking too long to execute and/or using too many resources. Did you try investigating that also?

Comment: If you just toss it into your address bar does it randomly take 9 seconds?  It sounds like your backend is at fault here.

Comment: Tried using DHC and the response was returned immediately using the same GET request.

Comment: Maybe this is the other candidate Kinpin mentioned. Can you include the template?

Comment: Feel free to have a look at the code yourself on my github: https://github.com/kgish/zmail-client

Comment: My backend isn't touched and on the network tab I see that the call to /folders isn't done until after 9 seconds. When I ran a profile devtools tells me that the app is (idle) for 9 secs :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the performance problem was caused by `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (argh).

When I load `index.html` as a file directly from the browser or use `adsf` instead, everything works fine.